# Android client can't access shared files from another account?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, shared-folders

I have an account shared with me.  Can see it on web, on Linux and Windows workstations, etc., but cannot see it on the android client.

Bug? or on purpose? or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Mike.

Answer (score 4):

Right now we don't expose shares in the Android client. It could be considered either a bug or a feature request  :)
Either way, it's on our horizon to extend the application, but I can't give you any estimated dates at the moment.

Comment: should be very useful.. any news about it? strange that nobody filled it as bug report, or at least feature request

Answer (score 0):

This is a lack of feature of Ubuntu One Files for Android.

I filled a bug report, if you are interested can subscribe it:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/+bug/1183670