# Shared directory (Ubuntu One) not showing up on my android device

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, apple, shared-folders

a friend has shared a directory on his Ubuntu account with me. His directory shows up on my windows devices (two of them), but does not show up on my android device (Nexus 7) using the android app, or on my Apple iPhone 5 using the apple app. All of these devices show up on my account as connected devices. I've even tried un-linking and re-linking my android Nexus 7, but the shared directory still doesn't show up.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please better explain/define '*Ubuntu account*'. ***Is this a network share, SAMBA, online somewhere, etc.***

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu One on my (first) Windows 7 pc, and signed up for an account. I then installed Ubuntu on another Windows 7 pc. I have also installed the iPhone Ubuntu app on my iPhone 5 and the Ubuntu android app on my Nexus 7 tablet. All good, I can see all of my Ubuntu files from each device. Then, my friend 'shared' a directory from his Ubuntu account with me. Now, when I open Ubuntu on both of my PCs, I see all my files and his shared directory. However, when I open the Ubuntu app on my Nexus 7 and on my iPhone 5, I only see my Ubuntu files, I do not see his shared directory

Comment: the Ubuntu account I'm referring to is the online cloud account at https://login.ubuntu.com/+login - and by the way, thanks for responding and helping ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/117360/android-client-cant-access-shared-files-from-another-account

Comment: The service is obsolete